# How to stop paste function repeating in shiny output?

Tags: r, shiny, paste

I would like to chose multiple options in select input and display them as output without the stem repeating. In this example, I would like to see

```
You chose NY NJ CT
```

instead of

```
You chose NY You chose NJ You chose CT
```

How do I stop the paste function from repeating "You chose"?

Here's the code for the shiny app:

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {
  
  
  # demoing group support in the `choices` arg
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                  list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                       `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                       `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")),
                  multiple = TRUE
      )),
      mainPanel(
      textOutput("result")
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$result <- renderText({
        paste("You chose", input$state)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Try `paste("You chose", paste(input$state, collapse = ", "))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user12728748, this solution worked:

```
paste("You chose", paste(input$state, collapse = ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just need to change the position of the paste function?

ie: `print("you choose", paste(input$state))`

Comment: Thanks for the idea Justin. This didn't work very well in the shiny app ```print("you choose", paste(input$state))```. The paste function suggested by user12728748 ```paste("You chose", paste(input$state, collapse = ", "))``` worked better in this situation. Perhaps, I need to change the render function to print or your answer to work for the app. I'll try that.

Comment: Interesting! I am not quite sure why the `collpase=", "` portion helped, I will look into it as well!

Comment: I think it is the issue with the print function rather than the ```collapse = ", "```

Comment: This is just how `paste` works. Consider `paste("text", 1:3)`, `paste("text", paste(1:3, collapse=" "))`, and `paste(c("text", 1:3), collapse = " ")` to see what happens...

Comment: Ahh! I ran the three and I see now. Thanks! I'm new to R so I appreciate it! `paste("test",1:3)` produces ` "test 1" "test 2" "test 3"`  while `paste("test", paste(1:3, collpase=" ")` does the same but puts  a space after the number and `paste(c("test", 1:3), collpase=" ")` tells R to paste `test` followed by `1:3` each separated by a space. Amazing!